# Getting an error that cannot resolve

Tags: java, compilation

After compiling my java program I get a bunch of errors and I don't know how to resolve them. Can anyone give me a hand? =/

```java
class Date{

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
        boolean answer = false;

        if(year % 4 == 0  &&(year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 != 0))
            answer = true;  
        else 
            answer = false;

       return answer;
    }
}


int returnDaysInMonth (int year, int month){

if (month==1||month==3||month==5||month==7||month==8||month==10||month==12){

     return 31;

} else if (month==4||month==6||month==9||month==11){

     return 30;

} else if(isLeapYear(year)){

     return 29;
} else {
       return 28;

}
}
```

Here are the compiling errors:

```
/Users/vlop/NetBeansProjects2/JavaLibrary1/src/Date.java:22: class, interface, or enum expected
public int returnDaysInMonth (int year, int month){
/Users/vlop/NetBeansProjects2/JavaLibrary1/src/Date.java:28: class, 
interface, or enum expected
} else if (month==4||month==6||month==9||month==11){
/Users/vlop/NetBeansProjects2/JavaLibrary1/src/Date.java:32: class, 
interface, or enum expected
} else if(isLeapYear(year)){
/Users/vlop/NetBeansProjects2/JavaLibrary1/src/Date.java:35: class, 
interface, or enum expected
} else {
/Users/vlop/NetBeansProjects2/JavaLibrary1/src/Date.java:38: class, 
interface, or enum expected
}
5 errors
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do a bunch of Java after your class declaration has been closed.

Proper indentation helps identify such issues:

```
class Date {
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        boolean answer = false;

        if(year % 4 == 0  &&(year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 != 0))
            answer = true;
        else 
            answer = false;

        return answer;
    }
} // End of class.

// WAT
int returnDaysInMonth (int year, int month) {

// etc.
```

Also, separate issue, but you could return the result of the boolean expression directly:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0)));
}
```

Even if you're not comfortable with that, you could still avoid some noise:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year % 4 == 0  &&(year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 != 0)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need brackets around methods

Comment: An example would make this much clearer - which lines need brackets, and where should the brackets be?

Answer (score 0):

your brackets are all messed up resulting in the class not being able to be resolved, are you using a compiler or ide like eclipse to program this because it should be telling you that there is an issue

Answer (score 0):

These are simplified method to find leap year.

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    assert year >= 1583; // not valid before this date.
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should look like this

```
class Date {

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {

    boolean answer = false;

    if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 != 0))

        answer = true;

    else
        answer = false;

    return answer;

}

int returnDaysInMonth(int year, int month) {

    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8
            || month == 10 || month == 12) {

        return 31;

    } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {

        return 30;

    } else if (isLeapYear(year)) {

        return 29;
    } else {
        return 28;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: but as stated there are already methods and libs in place for this type of thing, i would suggest that if you are doing anything with dates that you check out the joda date time library